# MP3 files are not loading in Mongodb with php

Tags: php, html, mongodb

I can successfully upload / download image files in Mongodb with php through GridFS, but when I try to upload mp3 file, nothing happens. Neither I get any error nor any it is uploaded and further I have checked the permission of the file it's very similar of those image files plus the file size is also not too big it is around 6mb only. But for unknown reason it is not being uploaded in the Mongodb database through GridFS with php.  Please help me loading the MP3 files to the database. The code used for uploading files is as below :

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0); 

   $m = new MongoClient();
   $gridfs = $m->selectDB('mydb')->getGridFS();
   $gridfs->storeUpload('pic', array('_id'=>$_POST['_id'],'Username' => _POST['username'] ));
echo 'File Uploaded Successfully';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storeUpload use storeFile as given below example
ex:

```
<?php
   // connect to the ‘myGrid’ GridFS
   $m = new Mongo();
   $db = $m->myDB;
   $myGrid = $db->getGridFS('myGrid');
   $some_file='path of your video or audio file';
   // some extra data you may want to store with your file
  $data_array = array(
            'mime' => mime_content_type($some_file),
            'timestamp' => time(),

       );
   // store a file into the GridFS
   $myGrid->storeFile($some_file, $data_array);
  ?>
```